# Is there a way to mark accounts like give an account a property value?

Tags: smart-contract, accounts

Let's say I'm making a game character and each eos account is a unique character. Is there a way to mark an account with different properties like strength, speed, durability, etc....

Comment: yeah you can use the account name as the primary key in the contract RAM table and use the properties as fields in the struct. monstereos had something similar I think

Comment: link to examples?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use use multi-index tables to store the relevant data in the persistent storage while indexing it by account name. To access the persistent storage, you'd need to have bought RAM to pay for the storage while it's in use.

Example adapted from [the docs](https://developers.eos.io/eosio-home/docs/data-persistence):

```
struct [[eosio::table]] mystruct 
{
    name            key; 
    uint64_t        strength;
    uint64_t        durability; 
    uint64_t        speed; 

    uint64_t primary_key() const { return key.value; } // getter for primary key
};


typedef eosio::multi_index<"mystruct"_n, mystruct> datastore;
```

Other projects such as [EOSKnights](https://github.com/bada-studio/knights_contract) show a working app using similar concepts.

Comment: where is this persistent storage? I thought EOS doesn't store data like this? Or wouldn't it be too expensive?

Comment: yes, you need to buy RAM to have access to the persistent storage, and at the moment it's about 0.1 EOS per KiB (updated my answer to mention RAM as well)

Comment: You don't necessarily have to buy RAM, you can put it on the users' account. So each user needs a small amount of RAM and they all share the cost.